# jQuery UI Tabs - show option resets windows position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

When I use tabs in jQuery UI with simple template like this:

```
<div id="products-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#product-1">Product 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#product-2">Product 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="product-1">
        Product 1
    </div>
    <div id="product-2">
        Product 2
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#products-tabs').tabs();
```

Then everything works fine. But I want to add effect of different swaping between tabs. For example like this:

```
$('#products-tabs').tabs({
    show: { effect: "fadeIn", duration: 800 }
});
```

It works, but when I have the tabs at the bottom of the page, then when I click on one of the tabs the position of the window resets back to top. How can I prevent it?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/46a8y/3/ (just scroll to the bottom in output window to see what I mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your jquery version, jquery 2.1.0 or 1.9.1 work fine.

Comment: Sorry, it's not an option here. We got lots of scripts which would stop working if I changed jquery to newer version unfortunately (and correcting them would be ... meh)

Comment: I've changed my mind, I made a simple correction to use different versions of jquery on different modules so your solution seems the best at the moment. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

after a tab is activated you can call an callback to jump to the bottom of your page?

```
activate: function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
}
```

like this: http://jsfiddle.net/46a8y/4/

Comment: seems like an option I will use if no one comes up with anything better... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your tabs div inside another fixed-height div:

```
<div id="wrapper">your tabs</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46a8y/7/)

Comment: If it complies your requirements you have to set the wrapper-div hieght as your highest tab.